# change file persmissions filezilla command line windows

Tags: joomla, ftp, chmod, rights, filezilla

How do I change the file permissions in filezilla with the command line?
I tried 'SITE CHMOD 755 templates' but that only changes the folder 'templates'.
I want to chmod all files in the templates folder and the subfolders in there.
I know you can do this by clicking rmb om the templates folder etc. but that is way to slow I was hoping the command line would be faster?

If not, what is the best way to change a lot of file permissions on your server fast?

I'm using filezilla in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per ssh if possbile:
Login on the remoteserver and simply do a

```
chmod -R 755 diretory
```

On the command line i would use lftp, which is IMHO the best command line ftp client (in Windows, install/run the cygwin setup.exe program and look for 'lftp' in the net section of the package list.). It supports

```
chmod -R 777 directory
```

In filezialla only per UI i guess:

Select the main folder, set to 755 and select the "recurse into subdirectories"

http://www.codeunit.co.za/2008/07/18/remotely-changing-multiple-linux-file-permissions-with-filezilla/

[image]