# server not reading css and js files

Tags: html, css, file-upload, server, path

I have created a website using css, js and jquery, and everything works fine on my local machine, but after uploading it to the server, it was only reading the index.html file, leaving out the css and js. Below you can see the website's structure, after being uploaded to the server, on FileZilla.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpkh2.png)

I have decided to delete everything, re-check the paths and upload them again, but now all I get is a "403 Forbidden" message, saying that "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Answer (score 1):

Check [file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6000873/855636) of all the files.

Triple check file paths

```
/www/style.css
./www/style.css
^ Notice this dot
```

The above are **two completely differnet paths**. My *guess* is, that the second one is the correct one and should lead to style in your specific example

Comment: Well. Its either paths or the file permissions. Without knowing how did you set the paths and how the folder structure looks below "etc" and "www" there is no help for you left

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep looking into it.